# JUnit 5 testing

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4, junit5

How do i achieve full branch coverage on the 3 methods in this class with junit test cases using java and the @test annotation.

```
public class StringStack {
private int capacity = 10;
private int pointer = 0;
private String[] objects = new String[capacity];

public void push(String o) {
    if (pointer >= capacity)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack exceeded capacity!");
    objects[pointer++] = o;

}
public String pop() {
    if (pointer <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack empty");
    return objects[--pointer];

}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return pointer <= 0;

}
```

i have written the following test casses and i have achieved this for the isEmpty() method although i am struggling to write test cases for the other two methods because they both return object pointers and i do not know how to initialize that in my test file.

```
class squareTest {

    //1.
    @Test 
    public void push() {

        StringStack push1 = new StringStack();
        String e2 = push1.pop();
        try {
            Assert.fail( "Should have thrown an exception" );
        assertEquals(IllegalArgumentException("Stack empty"), e2);
        //java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stack empty

        }catch (Exception e) {
            String expmessage = "I should get this message";


        }




    }

    @Test
    public void testTC3()
    {
        try {
            StringStack.push(o);
            fail(); // if we got here, no exception was thrown, which is bad
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            final String expected = "Legal Values: Package Type must be P or R";
            assertEquals( expected, e.getMessage());
        }        
    }

    //3.EMPTY TEST CASES
    @Test
    public void empty()
    {
        StringStack test2 = new StringStack();
        boolean e1 = test2.isEmpty();
        assertEquals(true, e1);
    } 
    @Test
    public void notEmpty()
    {
        StringStack test3 = new StringStack();
        boolean ne1 = test3.equals("im not empty");
        assertEquals(false, ne1);
    }
}
```

Comment: By writing tests. But why do you want to achieve 100% branch coverage?

Comment: Don't post what you have in comments. Edit our question.

Comment: If you're using [tag:junit5], why does this question have a [tag:junit4] tag?

Comment: And please show your tests. Again the question: why achieve 100% branch coverage? I would suggest to write valuable tests, e.g. behavioral tests.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Start by fixing that. Then realize that putting assertions inside a try block is not what you need to do. What you need to do (if you really don't want the support of JUnit 5 for exception testing) is to put the call to your method inside the try block. Some of your tests don't make much sense to me. I would advise, before writing the code, to write a textual description of your test, like "popping an element from an empty stack should throw an exception because there's nothing to be popped". Doing that for testTC3 would probably make you realize your mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe below test while help to get full coverage.

> push method test

- pointer >= capacity

  ```
  @Test(exception = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void push_PointerGreaterThanCapacity_ExceptionThrow(){
      WhiteBox.setInternalState(yourObject, "pointer",11);
      String inputString  = "Hello";
      yourObject.push(inputString);
  }
  ```
- pointer < capacity

  ```
  @Test
  public void push_PointerSmallerThanCapacity_ExceptionThrow(){
      String inputString  = "Hello";
      yourObject.push(inputString);
      int pointer = WhiteBox.getInternalState(yourObject,"pointer");
      String[] objects = WhiteBox.getInternalState(yourObject,"objects");

      assertEquals(inputString, objects[pointer-1]);
  }
  ```

> pop method test

- pointer < 0

  ```
  @Test(exception = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void pop_PointerNegative_ExceptionThrow(){
      WhiteBox.setInternalState(yourObject, "pointer",-1);
      String inputString  = "Hello";
      yourObject.push(inputString);
  }
  ```
- pointer > 0

  ```
  @Test
  public void pop_pointerGreaterThenZero_PopValue(){
      //set pointer
      WhiteBox.setInternalState(yourObject, "pointer",2);
      String[] stringList = {"String0","String1","String2"};
      //object array
      WhiteBox.setInternalState(yourObject, "objects",stringList);

      String actualOutput = yourObject.pop();
      assertEquals(actualOutput, stringList[1]);
  }
  ```

Here, yourObject is the object of class which one you test.

Comment: I am recieving an error on yourObject what would i replace it with ? Also thank you so much for this helpful answer

Comment: that is the class object for call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example for the first function

```
public void push(String o) {
    if (pointer >= capacity)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack exceeded capacity!");
    objects[pointer++] = o;
}
```

You need 3 unity tests to fully cover this one

1. For pointer == capacity
2. One for pointer > capacity
3. And the last one for pointer < capacity

For branch coverage you need only 1 and 3 or 2 and 3 though I would suggest all three for critical pieces of functionality.

Comment: "*You need 3 unity tests to fully cover this one*" - I would challenge this statement. If you mean branch coverage, one "only" needs two cases (`pointer < capacity` and `pointer >= capacity`). If one wants to achieve C3 coverage... well... good luck.

Comment: For branch coverage I would agree. I find that writing tests for edge cases though is the easy to discover the real logic errors. That's why I said to fully cover that. I will update the answer to make it clear.